# How to resolve Sonar "Invoke method(s) only conditionally"

Tags: java, json, logging, sonarqube, gson

My code looks like:

```java
logger.debug("Message:Request", new Gson().toJson(req));
```

Sonar issue says:

> Invoke method(s) only conditionally.

How do I fix this line of code?

Comment: I tried to create a separate variable and assigned the value of new Gson().toJson(req) to it. Use the variable in logger.debug. It worked!

Comment: No, it "worked" in the sense that SonarQube no longer complains, but this is completely the wrong way to go about it. You are calling the expensive function `Gson().toJson()` even when you don't need to log the value (e.g. if you're not debugging). What you should do is what the SonarQube rule description suggests (see the answer below) which is to only call that function if you are actually logging at debug level. Also, note that your logger.debug call is going to ignore the JSON string you pass to it unless you add "{}" to the first argument.

Answer (score 5):

In general please have a look at the SonarQube rule descriptions to understand what they mean, whether they are relevant for your usecase and how to fix the issues. In this case the [rule description](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/tag/performance/RSPEC-2629) shows how this can be solved:

> ```java
> // since Java 8, we can use Supplier, which will be evaluated lazily
> logger.log(Level.SEVERE, () -> "Something went wrong: " + message);
> ```
>
> *or*
>
> ```java
> if (LOG.isDebugEnabled() {
>     // this is compliant, because it will not evaluate if log level is above debug.
>     LOG.debug("Unable to open file " + csvPath, e);
> }
> ```

It depends on the logging framework you are using which of these solutions is possible.

Comment: Exactly, "RTFM" can get you a long way, most of the time. SonarQube provides really good explanations and examples with the majority of their rules. Read them :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution in case you get this warning for a `log.error` or `log.severe`:

Suppress the warning with eg `//NOSONAR` in this specific case. For `debug` and `info` levels this warning makes sense - they should not slow down your application when you don't use them. But for `error` it does not. Sonar is basically telling you to optimize your program for the scenario where you run into errors but are configured to not print error messages. This is an incredibly stupid thing to optimize.

Sonar does recognize that fact by disabling the warning when the log is inside a `catch`-block. But all `log.error`-calls appear in 'failure'-paths, even if the control structure is something different.